# Range posts in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In order to show only 4 posts I'm using the following snippet:

```
{% for post in site.categories.mycategory limit:4 %}
  {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, in a second container, I need to show posts from 5 to 8, then posts from 9 to 12 and so on.
Is there a filter to range posts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [offset](https://gist.github.com/smutnyleszek/9803727#for-loop) to skip the first elements:

```
{% for post in site.categories.mycategory limit:4 offset:4 %}
  {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also consider [pagination](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I've also found the previous answer very interesting.